# How to order by address, the framework of address is cellname{p}#{q}T{r}

Tags: mysql, sql

I use MySQL 5.1.72-community.

I have an address column, there is no space in the address. The framework of address is cellname{p}#{q}T{r}, the p,q,r is number. Some like:

```
 elephant4#3T201

 elephant5#12T201

 Lida2#12T304

 Lida1#5T102

 ...
```

But sometimes, there is no {p}#, like:

```
 swan2T101

 swan4T502
 ...
```

Now, I want order by address, first by cellname(text pattern), then by {p}(number pattern), then by {q}(number pattern).

For example, if the data like:

```
 elephant5#2T201

 elephant14#3T201

 elephant4#3T201

 elephant5#12T201

 Lida1#5T102

 Lida2#12T304

 beta1T101

 beta11T201

 beta2T301

 swan2T101

 swan4T502
```

I want the result like:

```
 beta1T101

 beta2T301

 beta11T201

 elephant4#3T201

 elephant5#2T201

 elephant5#12T201

 elephant14#3T201

 Lida1#5T102

 Lida2#12T304

 swan2T101

 swan4T502
```

How to do this by sql please?

Comment: What's the expected result based on the example data?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Sorry, I put an example there now.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
SELECT testcol FROM testar ORDER BY testcol;
```

Comment: Thank you. But it can not work on MySQL 5.1.72. All the binrayColumn is 0.